# textView resizes to longest TextView in the tableLayout

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout

When i add a textView to a row in a tableLayout.. it resizes all the ones before it, if it is longer in length. all i want it is, for every textView to be wrapped to text length.. the pics will explain better

```
        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.messhistory);
        TextView edit = new TextView(this);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        //edit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edit.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
        if(true)
        {
            ImageView iv= new ImageView(this);
            row.addView(iv);
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        }
        row.addView(edit,new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(row);
```

**Before adding a longer text**

[image]

**After adding a long text**

[image]

Comment: `if(true){...;}` ? :D

Answer (score 1):

You are using same instance of `edit` everywhere, so next time when you get your text larger, it wraps the larger text, so it makes its(edit) previous instances larger as well.
One possible solution is to create a new instance of edit each time you add your text.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the documentation on `TableLayout`, I came acrross this:

> The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in
>   that column. However, a TableLayout can specify certain columns as
>   shrinkable or stretchable by calling setColumnShrinkable() or
>   setColumnStretchable(). If marked as shrinkable, the column width can
>   be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as
>   stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space.

So, the behavior you are noticing is by design. But to get a similar effect(without the fixed cloumn width), give this code a try:

```
// Define a Linearlayout instead of a TableLayout in your layout file
// Set its width to match_parent
// Set its orientation to "vertical"
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.someLinearLayout);

// This serves the same purpose as the TableRow
LinearLayout llRow = new LinearLayout(this);

TextView edit = new TextView(this);

edit.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));

ImageView iv= new ImageView(this);

llRow.addView(iv);

iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams  llLeft = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams  llRight = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

llLeft.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

llRight.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

// You can set the LayoutParams llLeft(messages appear on left) or 
// llRight(messages appear on right) Add "edit" first to make the imageview appear on right

llRow.addView(edit, llLeft);

ll.addView(llRow);
```